# RangeError: Invalid key length for Paytm gateway checksum

Tags: node.js, payment-gateway, paytm

When I send a GET request I get an Internal server error for the below code.
I am using strapi and integrating Paytm gateway.

This is my code to initiate payment:

```
paytmParams.body = {
  "requestType": "Payment",
  "mid": process.env.MID,
  "websiteName": "YOUR_WEBSITE_NAME",
  "orderId": "ORDERID_98765",
  "callbackUrl": "http://localhost:1337/api/orders/posttransaction",
  "txnAmount": {
    "value": "1.00",
    "currency": "INR",
  },
  "userInfo": {
    "custId": "CUST_001",
  },
};

/*
* Generate checksum by parameters we have in body
* Find your Merchant Key in your Paytm Dashboard at https://dashboard.paytm.com/next/apikeys 
*/
let checksum = await PaytmChecksum.generateSignature(JSON.stringify(paytmParams.body), 
process.env.MKEY);
```

GitHub Repo: https://github.com/anmol009a/my-shop/tree/master/backend

Error:

```
RangeError: Invalid key length
at Cipheriv.createCipherBase (node:internal/crypto/cipher:116:19)
at Cipheriv.createCipherWithIV (node:internal/crypto/cipher:135:3)
at new Cipheriv (node:internal/crypto/cipher:243:3)
at Object.createCipheriv (node:crypto:138:10)
at Function.encrypt (backend\node_modules\paytmchecksum\PaytmChecksum.js:8:23)
at Function.calculateChecksum (backend\node_modules\paytmchecksum\PaytmChecksum.js:90:24)
at Function.generateSignatureByString (backend\node_modules\paytmchecksum\PaytmChecksum.js:52:24)
at async Object.exampleAction (backend\src\api\order\controllers\custom.js:38:20)
at async returnBodyMiddleware (backend\node_modules\@strapi\strapi\lib\services\server\compose-endpoint.js:52:18)
at async policiesMiddleware (backend\node_modules\@strapi\strapi\lib\services\server\policy.js:24:5)
```

Comment: Can you share the headers info you are sending ? or you can try this example https://gist.github.com/amljs/bdaa89095061cd52fedf617158c69d68

Comment: i am sending default postman headers

Comment: As per the documentation, body is not required as argument for this method. 
var paytmParams = {};
paytmParams["MID"] = "YOUR_MID_HERE";
paytmParams["ORDERID"] = "YOUR_ORDER_ID_HERE";
var paytmChecksum = PaytmChecksum.generateSignature(paytmParams, "YOUR_MERCHANT_KEY");

Original source : https://business.paytm.com/docs/checksum/#createchecksum

Comment: var paytmChecksum = PaytmChecksum.generateSignature(body, "YOUR_MERCHANT_KEY"); 
from the same source but it is a JSON request.
Also, I copied the Code from Paytm website, so I don't think there is a problem in that.
As far as I understand error is occurring in Function createcipheriv(), you can see it in error and the path for same is given.
Please check it at repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace Paytm MKEY and MID with keys provided by Paytm.
Or use ScryptSync function to generate Mkey.

```
crypto.scryptSync(password, salt, keylen[, options])
```